# How to Uncheck All Radio Button inside GridView using JQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a Radio Button inside GridView. I want to Uncheck all the asp.net Radio Button except the current Selected one using JQuery. I have tried but no results..!

HTML Markup:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbUser" runat="server" kID='<%# Eval("kID")%>' class="rdbUser" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".rdbUser", function() {
                var selectedRadio = $(this).attr('id');

                //var newrdo = $("input:radio.rdbUser:checked");
                //$(".rdbUser").prop('checked', false);
                //$('#' + selectedRadio).prop('checked', true);
                //$('input:radio[class=rdbUser]').prop('checked', false);
//                $('.rdbUser').removeAttr('checked');

                var kID = $(this).attr('kID');
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnKioskID").val(kID);

                alert("selected Radio : " + kID);
            });
```

On SeeingMarkup in Chrome:

**Checked RadioButton:**

```
<span class="rdbUser" kid="2"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_rdbUser" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$rdbUser" value="rdbUser"></span>
```

**Unchecked RadioButton:**

```
<span class="rdbUser" kid="21"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl05_rdbUser" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl05$rdbUser" value="rdbUser"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(document).on("click", ".rdbUser", function() {
    // to uncheck all radios which are not checked
    $("input[type=radio].rdbUser").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop('checked',true);// check the current one only
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [RadioButton.GroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

> Use the GroupName property to specify a grouping of radio buttons to create a mutually exclusive set of controls. You can use the GroupName property when only one selection is possible from a list of available options.
>
> When this property is set, only one RadioButton in the specified group can be selected at a time.

However you can try this code using jquery

```
$(document).on("click", ".rdbUser", function() {
    //Check if this radio button is checked
    if($(this).find("input[type=radio]").is(':checked'))
    {
        //Use .not() to exclude this
        //Use .prop() to set checked to false
        $(".rdbUser").not(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `change` event instead of `click`

IF using jquery version > 1.6 use `prop` else use `attr`

```
$(".rdbUser").change(function(){ 
   if($(this).prop("checked")){
     $("[id^='rdbUser']").not(this).prop("checked",false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!. 'grdOrganization' is the Id of GridView.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ResetRadioBtns(rb) {
            var gv = document.getElementById("<%=grdOrganization.ClientID%>");
            var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var row = rb.parentNode.parentNode;
            for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
                if (rbs[i].type == "radio") {
                    if (rbs[i].checked && rbs[i] != rb) {
                        rbs[i].checked = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }    

    </script>

      <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnMaster" runat="server" onclick="ResetRadioBtns(this)" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```